# Trouble translating c++ with pre and post increment operators to python

Tags: c++, python

I'm trying to work out what the equivalent `a[++j]=*pr++;` in the following code (which comes from a MatLab mex file) is in Python. I've found out that 'pr' is a pointer to the first element of the input array, but I can't get my head around what is happening to j. Can someone explain what is happening there in simple terms without pointers etc?

```
rf3(mxArray *array_ext, mxArray *hs[]) {
double *pr, *po, a[16384], ampl, mean;
int tot_num, index, j, cNr;
mxArray *array_out;

tot_num = mxGetM(array_ext) * mxGetN(array_ext);
pr = (double *)mxGetPr(array_ext);

array_out = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(3, tot_num-1, mxREAL);
po = (double *)mxGetPr(array_out);

j = -1;
cNr = 1;
for (index=0; index<tot_num; index++) {
    a[++j]=*pr++;
    while ( (j >= 2) && (fabs(a[j-1]-a[j-2]) <= fabs(a[j]-a[j-1])) ) {
        ampl=fabs( (a[j-1]-a[j-2])/2 );
        switch(j)
{
            case 0: { break; }
            case 1: { break; }
            case 2: {
                mean=(a[0]+a[1])/2;
                a[0]=a[1];
                a[1]=a[2];
                j=1;
                if (ampl > 0) {
                    *po++=ampl;
                    *po++=mean;
                    *po++=0.50;
                }
                break;
            }
            default: {
                mean=(a[j-1]+a[j-2])/2;
                a[j-2]=a[j];
                j=j-2;
                if (ampl > 0) {
                    *po++=ampl;
                    *po++=mean;
                    *po++=1.00;
                    cNr++;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
for (index=0; index<j; index++) {
    ampl=fabs(a[index]-a[index+1])/2;
    mean=(a[index]+a[index+1])/2;
    if (ampl > 0){
        *po++=ampl;
        *po++=mean;
        *po++=0.50;
    }
}
/* you can free the allocated memeory */
/* for array_out data                 */
  mxSetN(array_out, tot_num - cNr);
  hs[0]=array_out;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specifically asked about:

```
a[++j]=*pr++;
```

j is being incremented before the assignment. In python the left hand side would be:

```
a[j+1]
```

and you would also then need to increment j before you use it next:

```
j += 1
```

The right hand side simply accesses the current position and *then* increments the position in the array. In python you would probably just use an iterator for your array.

BTW, you might find it difficult to do a line-by-line 'translation' of the code. I would suggest writing down the steps of the algorithm and then tackling it fresh in python, if that is what you need.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what happens:

1. Increment `j` by 1
2. assign to `a[j]` value pointed at by `pr`
3. increment `pr`.

In this order.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there aren't pointers, so how you translate this will depend on how you decide to represent `pr`. If you think of the pointer as a copy of the list `pr = array_ext[:]`, the line you've highlighted would be something like

```
j = j + 1
a[j] = pr.pop(0)
```

For greater efficiency (and a closer parallel to what the C code is doing), you could use `pr` as an index into the list `array_ext`, starting it at `0`. Then, the line you highlighted does this:

```
j = j + 1
a[j] = array_ext[pr]
pr = pr + 1
```